# DeleteCases and Pattern Matching With NumberQ

Tags: pattern-matching

If I have a list:

```
list:={{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,"a"}}
```

And I would like to delete the row with a string character, the following works:

```
DeleteCases[list, {_, _?StringQ}]
```

returns

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
```

However, if I use:

```
DeleteCases[list, {_, _?\[Not]NumberQ}]
```

The result is

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, a}}
```

I'm not sure how to generate the 'not' expression in the web interface, but the [Not] operator above is generated in Mathematica by -esc-not-esc.  I thought I had effectively used the expression "not a numeric".  In fact, StringQ identifies the element as a string and it is removed from the list.  But isn't it also not NumberQ?  So, check a single expression:

```
NumberQ["a"]
```

which returns

```
False
```

and, when I check

```
\[Not] NumberQ["a"]
```

the expression returns

```
True
```

That all seems to work as I expected.

Then, why doesn't my formulation of (not)NumberQ drop the row in DeleteCases?  Precedence?

Comment: `!NumberQ` is not a function `_?` must be followed by a function. You can use `_?(Composition[Not,NumberQ])` or you can use `x_ /; Not@NumberQ[x]`

Comment: Use `_?(Not[NumberQ[#]]&)` or `_?(Not @* NumberQ)` instead

Comment: Also, a tip: `?` has very high precedence. Parentheisise everything that comes after it. Even the `Composition` example above must be parethesised.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble here is that `?` takes its right hand side and uses it as the head of a predicate. `FullForm` of `\[Not] NumberQ` is `Not[NumberQ]`. Making that the head, you get `Not[NumberQ]["a"]` for your string, when what you need is `Not[NumberQ["a"]]` to do what you want. The way to do it is to make an expression that's sensible as a head. The idiomatic way is:

```
DeleteCases[list, {_, _?(\[Not] NumberQ[#] &)}]
```

using a pure function as head, allowing you to insert the argument in the right part of the body. Alternatively, you can make a named definition:

```
nnq[x_] := Not[NumberQ[x]]
DeleteCases[list, {_, _?nnq}]
```